# Vertical coordinate

Tags: digital-preservation

Is there a common agreement on the vertical coordinate direction in photography? So if I am discussing a photo with someone on the phone and want to refer to a face in the upper left quadrant, would it be

- (0.25, 0.25), i.e. (0, 0) in the upper left corner;
- or (0.25, 0.75), i.e. (0, 0) in the bottom left corner?

I need it for a self-made family photo web-site, where people should be able to comment on an untagged face.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question mighe be better asked if there a coordinate system for XMP metadata (which is how the faces are stored, so could be considered a standard frame of reference..)

I'm trying to look up the spec for XMP face data, and have yet to find where the (0,0) point is, but it's a beginning.

http://www.organizepictures.com/2013/09/everything-you-need-to-know-about-picasa-metadata

[image]

Ah, [this](http://mamclain.com/?page=Blog_Programing_Python_Picasa_XMP_Face_Extractor) is helpful as well, but still doesn't explicitly tell you the origin:

> Noting that I use the term minor caveat here sardonically since the
>   normalization and relative encoding of the XMP tag (x, y, width,
>   height) is either not documented or is so currently obfuscated within
>   existing documentation that determining that the provided XMP X,Y
>   coordinates are actually referring to the center of the rectangle
>   rather than to a corner of the rectangle (which is traditional) is a
>   frustrating process for the uninitiated.

...his [code](http://mamclain.com/?page=Blog_Programing_Python_Picasa_XMP_Face_Extractor) seems to assume the same coordinate system as the Image class he imports.

[If it is PIL, (0, 0) is the upper left corner.](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/concepts.htm)

Comment: If XMP can be used as the guidance, then http://metadataworkinggroup.com/pdf/mwg_guidance.pdf gives an answer: "the origin of the image is the upper left."